# Using string as parameter name

Tags: python, function

I have the following functions:

```
def train(data,**kwargs):
    train_model(data,**kwargs)

def test_train_parameters(data1,data2,parameter_to_test, parameter_value):
    train(data1,**kwargs)
    train(data2,**kwargs)
```

Train function has some optional parameters, such as gamma, lambda, num_rounds and so on. Train with data1 would be called without any modified parameter, but train with data2 would be called with a parameter modified and it's value. For example, let's say I want a gamma = 5, I would code:

```
test_train_parameters(parameter_to_test = 'gamma', parameter_value = 5)
```

And the function would be called as follow:

```
train(data1)
train(data2, gamma = 5)
```

Thus, this can not be done just calling the parameter as `test_train_parameters(gamma = 5)`because it would interfere with the first train.

I have been searching on google but I have been unable to find something that fits my case (I have found eval, getattr, passing list... but those are for other things). How could I make it?

Comment: What if you pass two dictionaries (one specifically for each `train`) - therefore parameters could be passed explicitly.

Comment: You can just do `train(data2,**kwargs, **{parameter_to_test: parameter_value})`. Or if `parameter_to_test` may appear in `kwargs`, do `train(data1,**kwargs); kwargs[parameter_to_test] = parameter_value; train(data2,**kwargs)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In python, kwargs are just dictionaries, so you can create a dictionary in your function with your arguments:

```
def test_train_parameters(data1,data2,parameter_to_test, parameter_value):
    train(data1)
    kwargs = {parameter_to_test: parameter_value}
    train(data2,**kwargs)
```

Comment: What if I already have other parameters passing as kwargs? Making kwargs[parameter_to_test] = parameter_value would be enough to add this one to the others?

Answer (score 1):

An `if` with every possible parameter? Like

```py
def test_train_parameters(data1,data2,parameter_to_test, parameter_value):
    train(data1)
    if parameter_to_test == 'alpha':
        train(data2, alpha=parameter_value)
    elif parameter_to_test == 'beta':
        train(data2, beta=parameter_value)
    elif parameter_to_test == 'gamma':
        train(data2, gamma=parameter_value)
```

I know it's not pleasing to the eye but it's a simple way to do it.

Comment: Well, there are like 50 parameters that can be modified, so it will be very tedious to make such a solution